# Why can't one "catch up on" sleep?

Tags: sleep

I've repeatedly heard it said by sleep experts that one cannot "catch up" on missed sleep.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> The best explanation of that statement I've heard so far is that a lack of sleep has physical effects on one's health, and those accumulate and cannot be reversed. Paraphrased and simplified, each missed hour of sleep shaves off an hour of your life, or something to that effect.

<sup>[citation needed]: Most recently in some interview with [Matthew Walker](https://www.sleepdiplomat.com), but I've heard other people state similar things.</sup>

Apparently it doesn't work to sleep 6 hours during the week and 13 hours during the weekend; that won't equal an average of 8 hours per night for your body and will have negative longterm effects.

Clearly though, it must be possible to "catch up" on sleep in *some* sense. If I don't sleep one night I will feel like crap the next day; but clearly after sleeping well for a few nights after that I will feel fine again, so my body must have returned to some normal equilibrium.

So, what exactly is meant by the statement that one can't catch up on sleep? Taken as an absolute statement it would mean you'd accumulate a lot of missing sleep time over the course of your life, and I don't really feel like I've missed several weeks or months worth of sleep right now; so this statement must require some qualification.

Comment: Blunt Analogy: You can’t drink 100l of water now and expect it to last 50 days. You can’t consume all the energy you need now and never it again in your entire life. You can’t train as much as possible in your youth and wait for your body to built up muscle mass in adulthood. And you can’t run out of oxygen now and catch up later.

Comment: Sure, but if I run out of oxygen now I'll be dead for the rest of my life. If I miss a night's sleep, I'm obviously _not_ going to be tired for the rest of my life. That's where I want some qualification for that statement.

Comment: You actually start to catch up after waking up from sleeping less than the ideal time for you. Feeling drowsy is not a direct consequence of a backlog of tasks the body should have done during sleep, it's nothing more than your body's indicator of the backlog, and you can shut that signal down by taking stimulants like coffee. It's similar to the gas indicator of your moving to the red zone, at that point there is still plenty of gas left but you should fill up the tank at the next opportunity. It's not that there is an actual fuel shortage.

Comment: Take e.g. [Paul Erdős' use of amphetamines](https://jrbenjamin.com/tag/paul-erdos/).

Comment: @Count You're just making  this worse for me…  According to you there _aren't_ any real drawbacks to sleeping too little? And/or you can "catch up" on sleep by not sleeping but popping pills instead?

Comment: @deceze there is, of course, a limit to what you can ask from your body. But even well within the limits, you will still feel the many feedback mechanisms of your body at work. You have to consider that the body you have evolved over hundreds of millions of years to survive in quite harsh conditions. While today we can eat and sleep as much as we want, that was not true 100,000 years ago. Any autonomous system that needs to take care of itself in conditions where it cannot count on always having access to the necessary supplies it needs, will have to go about things in a very pro-active way.

Comment: Another thing to consider when considering the health impacts of lack of sleep, is the fact that there is also a price to pay for sleeping more, simply due to being awake less. A person who dies at the age of 100 and has slept for an average of 8 hours throughout his life, will only have been awake for 66.7 years. If sleeping 6 hours instead of 8 hours causes a massive ten year reduction of life expectancy, then with 90 years of 6 hours sleep, the person would have been awake for 67.5 years.

Comment: @Count So how was Erdős able to apparently push his limits continually? He replaced sleep with amphetamines? If those are only turning off the warning signs but are not really replenishing the fuel, then there should have been a limit to that? Doesn't look like it had much of an impact on him after all. If that is so, "can't catch up on sleep" seems to mean that the concept of "catching up" is invalid, as there isn't really any "normal" baseline? Yet at the same time sleep experts strongly advise getting "enough" sleep…

Comment: Maybe to clarify what is confusing to me: if you imagine the body having some sort of "energy level" indicated by a fuel gauge, and being awake and active slowly drops the fuel level, and once you fall below a certain threshold you're really starting to be less effective, and sleeping fills up the fuel again, and running dry eventually kills you… in this scenario not being able to "catch up" means you can never refill to 100% if you've missed too many refills; which to me makes little sense. What's wrong about my view and/or that statement here?

Comment: The body strives to do more than what is strictly necessary. If you get adequate sleep in the sense of not feeling drowsy during the day, you'll have enough reserves to last a week doing hard exercise with hardly any sleep at all. If you sign up for the special forces, you'll be subject to such harsh training regimes. You may drop out, but even then you'll be surprised how much more you can do than you had ever imagined.

Comment: @Count That’s all well and good, but I still don’t know how to map that onto the “can’t catch up” statement. Does it invalidate it? Does it confirm it somehow? [Mu?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_(negative)#"Unasking"_the_question)

Comment: A similar question was asked with a well received answer from a neuroscience standpoint at https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/868/can-you-catch-up-on-sleep-over-the-weekend.

Comment: @Chris Very interesting. That seems to say that *short term* catching up doesn't work, but, while inconclusive, a long-term return to baseline is of course possible. Which would be what I expect and why the generic statement "can't catch up" seems so absurd.